# Convert lat long into geojson object

Tags: php, json, geometry, geojson

How can i convert my lat and long value into geojson object. I work on php platform.

Answer (score 17):

If I understand well, you want to build a string like this:

```
$my_geoJSON = '{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": ['.$longitude.' ,'.$latitude.'] }';
```

As as the specification for GeoJSON format ([RFC7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#appendix-A.1)) says:

> Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for projected
> coordinates, longitude, and latitude for geographic coordinates):
>
> ```
>  {
>      "type": "Point",
>      "coordinates": [100.0, 0.0]
>  }
> ```

Comment: I wonder why geoJSON uses longitude, latitude when almost everyone else uses lat,lng.

Comment: @SamuelBarbosa, it's cause most everyone else is wrong. Lng is the x coordinate and lat is y, so correct usage is lng, lat.

Answer (score 3):

Put all your Lat Long data in a CSV file and use the below online tool to create a GeoJson file. Verify it using http://geojson.io/ tool.

http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-geojson.htm

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should have a look to the geojson specification (http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id9) you can also view simple example that will certainly help you to create a simple geojson with you lat/lon.